# Add value to final getPrice() figure within magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

At the moment I am able to change the value of the "getPrice()" function within magento using the following code:

```
 $price = 19.99; 
 $_rate->setPrice($price); 
 $_rate->save(); 
 $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), ...)
```

This effectively means that it calls the finalprice to be 19.99. However, I need it to be able to add the 19.99 to the final price instead of overwriting it all together so instead it would effectively be:

```
$this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice() + $price, ...)
```

however i am struggling with this a great deal.

**Just to note**, i appreciate how using the "save()" method is overwriting the final price, its just i am not sure how to get around it! Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There is an event catalog_product_get_final_price ..you can capture that event and in your observer method get reference object of product and do

$product->setFinalPrice($price)

I am not giving you exact code so that you can figure this out yourself and have an idea on how to solve such problems..

Comment: Of course. With what you have suggested, will it not still just overwrite the price instead of adding a specific number to it? i'm thinking it might just be easier to add a handling fee and use the sales_quote_collect_totals_before event?

Comment: The event you mentioned works when you are working with cart total and need to modify it..what I have suggested is will change the price of product throughout the site..

Comment: Also u can append to final price by just getting the current final and appending with the value you want

Comment: Sorry i should have clarified that this is based on the shipping price. It is not something that will directly add a number to the product directly, but the delivery cost when it is in the cart. It is why i used the {getShippingPrice()} Thank you for the advice though it has helped me understand another event.